# Compiled contract bytecode not matching deployed one with any solc version

Tags: contract-development, web3.py, py-solc-x

As an academic exercise inspired by this [post](https://www.shawntabrizi.com/ethereum/verify-ethereum-contracts-using-web3-js-and-solc/), I'm trying to verify the LINK token contract, comparing the one I get from `Web3.py` to the result that I get from compiling the source code using `solcx`. According to the source, the minimum required version is v0.4.16, but since I have not been able to match the same bytecode (even ignoring the different versions metadata), I basically compiled the file with every possible version that solcx has offered me and compared them with the original, with no match.

What am I doing wrong? I've tried downloading the code from Etherscan and also from Github. A similar code written in JS using web3js does work.

```
from web3 import Web3
import solcx

source_file = "/<path>/contracts/LinkToken.sol"
contract_address = "0x514910771AF9Ca656af840dff83E8264EcF986CA"
contract_name = "LinkToken"
infura_id = "<my_id>"

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(f"https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/{infura_id}"))
blockchain_contract =  web3.eth.get_code(contract_address).hex()[2:] # strip leading 0x
print(blockchain_contract[:100], "blockchain")

for v in solcx.get_installable_solc_versions():
    try:
        solcx.install_solc(v)
        solcx.set_solc_version(v)
        compilation = solcx.compile_files(
            [source_file],
            output_values=["abi", "bin-runtime"],
            solc_version=v
        )
        contract_bytecode = compilation[f"{source_file}:{contract_name}"]['bin-runtime']
        print(contract_bytecode[:100], v, "compiled")
    except:
        pass
```

Output (only showing the first 100 characters):

```
606060405236156100b75763ffffffff7c010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060003504 blockchain
6080604052600436106100ba576000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ff 0.4.26 compiled
6080604052600436106100ba576000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ff 0.4.25 compiled
6080604052600436106100ba576000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ff 0.4.24 compiled
6080604052600436106100ba576000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ff 0.4.23 compiled
6080604052600436106100ba576000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ff 0.4.22 compiled
6060604052600436106100ba576000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ff 0.4.21 compiled
6060604052600436106100ba576000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ff 0.4.20 compiled
6060604052600436106100ba576000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ff 0.4.19 compiled
6060604052600436106100ba576000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ff 0.4.18 compiled
606060405236156100b8576000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ffffff 0.4.17 compiled
606060405236156100b8576000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ffffff 0.4.16 compiled
```

Comment: The contract on Etherscan is compiled with optimization enabled. Are you compiling with the same optimization parameters?

Comment: That was it, thank you. You can turn the comment into an answer and I'll happily select it.